# How to export website field for a contact where website is specific website type?

Tags: export

I select some contacts for export. In my field mappings, I add `Website` but it does not give me the option to choose a specific website type. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have a website type called Twitter Website, for storing Twitter "handles". Each website/handle contains 'twitter.com' (i.e., like www.twitter.com/joemcl )

So using Search -> Search Builder, I search for Contacts Website Like %twitter% , then select all search results, select Actions, then Add Contacts to a Group (or better perhaps, choose New Smart Group) to create a new Group of every contact who is a Twitter user.

The same can work for Facebook as a website type.

Obviously this won't work for type 'Work' or 'Home', which won't be in the website name, which is what I think you actually want.